# Unable to library "rgdal" and "gdalUtils" after upgrading to macOS big sur

Tags: gdal, rgdal, macos, gdalutils

I just upgraded my laptop to macOS big sur, but then I could not library "rgdal" and "gdalUtils". It threw me an error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
> Reason: image not found

It worked well under Catalina but not big sur.

Would anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happened to me, but worked after I uninstalled rgdal and reinstalled from source.

```
remove.packages("rgdal")
install.packages("rgdal", type = "source")
```

and then restart RStudio

Comment: Thanks, Bob! It works.